# programmatically setting cq:tags save blank value in the node in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am trying to programmatically extract data from a json string, converts into a string array and adding it as cq:tags property and corresponding values into a node, however when I do so, though **cq:tags property is added but with blank values.**

My node is something like this: `/content/<my project node>/ContentPage/jcr:content`

```
        ResourceResolver resolver = CommonUtils.getResourceResolver(resourceResolverFactory);

  String[] strValue = tagList.stream().toArray(String[]::new); // tagList has String values in form of array.
            Resource resource = resolver.getResource(CONTENT_DATA_NODE);
            if (resource != null) {
                Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
                if (node != null) {
                    NodeIterator nodeIterator = node.getNodes();
                    while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
                        innerNode = nodeIterator.nextNode();
                        innerNode.setProperty(CQ_TAGS, strValue);
                        innerNode.getSession().save();
                    }
                }
            }
```

and my sling user mapper service is `mybundle.core:datawrite=userdatawriter` , also if my resource resolverfactory is null, I get resolver from request directly.

Initially, I thought it could be an access issue, so I programmatically tried with any random property and value:
property: **xyz** , values: **aa,bb,cc,dd**
Which is written by my code without any issues, 
it is only when programmatically adding **cq:tags** is when the problem arises. Though I can add cq:tags with any long list of values manually without any issues, either from page properties or in the crxde node itself.

What am I missing here and doing wrong in the code which can not only add cq:tags but also overwrite if cq:tags exists.

P.S: my AEM version is AEM 6.5 SP2

Answer (score 2):

I can see the same thing happen in AEM 6.4.3. Immediately upon saving the property, the value can be read as expected. Here's a few quick examples I ran in the [AEM Groovy console](https://github.com/OlsonDigital/aem-groovy-console).

```
def node = getNode('/content/screens/we-retail/apps/virtual-showroom/en/jcr:content')
String[] arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
String[] tagArr  = ['we-retail:equipment', 'we-retail:activity/biking']
node.setProperty('foo', arr)
println node.getProperty('foo').values // prints the a, b,c tags
node.setProperty('cq:tags', tagArr)
session.save()
println node.getProperty('cq:tags').values // prints the a, b,c tags
println node.getProperty('foo').values // prints the a, b,c tags
```

However, upon inspecting the page in CRXDE, I can see that the property is empty. This does not happen when the values you use match existing tags in AEM. For example:

```
def node = getNode('/content/screens/we-retail/apps/virtual-showroom/en/jcr:content')
String[] arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
String[] tagArr  = ['we-retail:equipment', 'we-retail:activity/biking']
node.setProperty('foo', arr)
println node.getProperty('foo').values
node.setProperty('cq:tags', tagArr)
println node.getProperty('cq:tags').values // prints the we-retail tags
session.save()
println node.getProperty('foo').values
println node.getProperty('cq:tags').values // prints the we-retail tags
```

and the same values are visible in CRXDE.

This behaviour, I believe, is controlled by the *Day CQ Tagging Service* (`com.day.cq.tagging.impl.JcrTagManagerFactoryImpl`)

[image]

Unchecking the box will disable validation and allow you to persist those values. However, tagging a page with tags that don't exist will cause its own share of problems. Instead, I would suggest making sure to create those tags before using them.

Comment: but unchecking the tag validation will make content non searchable using tag which will negate whole idea to add tags.

Comment: @Ajay, how do you search for this content? It seems you're trying to use tags that don't exist in AEM, which is more likely to cause search issues than disabling this validation.

Comment: Dynamically first saving in /content/cq:tags and then reading it and setting into the page under cq:tags page props is a costly affair.

Comment: @Ajay you don't have to do that dynamically. You can prepare the right taxonomy beforehand and upload it. Where do the tag names you're trying to use come from?